# QPainter init painter and use it

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qpainter

I created a class called painter and created the `QPainter` p in the constructor passing the `QMainWindow` as a parameter.

So in the mainwindow.h i added:

```
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui; // Created by the QT
    Painter* p;
```

In the mainwindow.cpp i added

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    p=new Painter(this);
}
```

and

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    p->render(this);
}
```

Painter.h

```
#ifndef PAINTER_H
#define PAINTER_H
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

class Painter
{
private:
    QPainter* painter;
    bool init;

public:
    Painter(QMainWindow* m);
    ~Painter();

    void render(QMainWindow* m);
};

#endif // PAINTER_H
```

and painter.cpp

```
#include "painter.h"

Painter::Painter(QMainWindow* m)
{
    painter=new QPainter(m);
    //init=false;
}

void Painter::render(QMainWindow* m)
{
    painter->drawLine(10, 3,123, 909);
}
```

It doesn't draw a thing.

If i do

```
void Painter::render(QMainWindow* m)
{
    painer->begin(m);
    painter->drawLine(10, 3,123, 909);
}
```

It render the line and after 2-3 seconds it closes

The only way to make it work is to do

```
void Painter::render(QMainWindow* m)
{
    QPainter p(m);
    p.drawLine(10, 3,123, 909);
}
```

But it seems stupid initialize the p on every frame, it works like that.
There's a way to just initialize the screen one time or make the begin work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with

```
painter->begin(this->m);
painter->drawLine(10, 2, 1232, 1222);
painter->end();
```

It seems stupid to me, but its better than declarate it on every frame.
If someone have a better idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `QPainter` how it's meant to be. Essentially, a `QPainter` is meant to be created using

```
QPainter p(this);
```

**inside** the paint event handler. If you need, you can still pass the painter around using a pointer, but you're likely to hit problems like that if you use too many pointers to `QPainter`.

My understanding is that the painter gets initialized properly only when there's a paint event going on, which is why your initialization in `Painter::Painter(QMainWindow* m)` produces a non-functional `QPainter`.